# msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I created a vs 2010 win 32 program (Operation system: Win 8-64bit)

Then, I tried to convert this win32 program in to x64 by doing like this:

```
 Configuration Manager -> new solution platform (select x64) -> copy settings from win32
```

The vs2010 created a new x64 program based on the previous win32 program.

However, when I tried to compile and run the x64 program, there is a single error:
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

By renaming both win32 version and x64 version of msvcprtd.lib, I found the program is still using the win32 msvcprtd.lib.

I checked and found msvcprtd.lib is in $(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64. Moreover:

Library Directories -> Inherited values has included all the necessary directories (I think):

```
$(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64
$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64
$(WindowsSdkDir)lib\x64
```

I also checked the 3rd party libraries and dlls the program is using are of x64 version.

My question is why the program is still using the win32 msvcprtd.lib and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you "clean" your project?

Comment: Yeah, cleaned and rebuilt

Answer (score 5):

In the project Library Directories, be sure you change

`$(VCInstallDir)lib` and `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib`

to

`$(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64` and `$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib\amd64`

Answer (score 2):

After searching I came across an useful page [MSDN Info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b11d09d-2eb3-4767-8adc-a0b7398215d9/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x86-conflicts-with-target-machine-type-x64). *"It is a known problem that on occasions VC picks up certain settings from older versions of VC installed and causes these kinds of problems."*

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by adding the following:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64**

Anyway, don't hesitate to search the **msvcprtd.lib** file directly from Visual Studio installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem.It comes rarely and occasionally when we create new project for X64 platform.

Here is the solution: for X64 platform
In Configuration properties-->

1.Include directories -> $(VCInstallDir)PlatformSDK\include;$(IncludePath);

2.Library directories -> $(VCInstallDir)PlatformSDK\lib;$(LibraryPath);